# Oops: this document is published but is not in the cache

Tags: umbraco

I've created a new document type and created a page from this type. I've filled out all the required fields and published the page and I get the following error in the Link to document field

> Oops: this document is published but is not in the cache (internal error)

and the following error in the log file

> 2013-06-08 18:03:14,209 [59] WARN  Umbraco.Web.Routing.NiceUrlProvider - [Thread 5] Couldn't find any page with nodeId=3198. This is most likely caused by the page not being published.

I've "Republish entire site", I've published my homepage "including all sub-pages" and "Include unpublished child pages". I've removed my umbraco.config and bounced IIS (it's actually running in VS dev server).

I am using umbraco v 4.11.8.

Comment: Does Umbraco have permissions to write to the umbraco.config?

Comment: I got this error when I cleared the courier folder in App_Data and tried to rebuild the cache. I had to do it because courier was misbehaving despite working well on two other servers. Clearing the cache caused it to get even more messed up :(

Comment: Stopping the site, dumping the cache, and forcing it to rebuild does restore the site for me. But doesn't solve the "problem" in answering why this happens in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known, but as yet un-fixed, issue in Umbraco 6. [Details ( and some workarounds) here](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-3145)

Answer (score 7):

Republish the whole site from the main node.

[Our.Umbraco.Org](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/39296-Oops-this-document-is-published-but-is-not-in-the-cache-%28internal-error%29?p=1) <--

Answer (score 0):

This package should fix the issue:

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/path-fixup